# How can I get the population and density for a particlular region infected by the COVID-19 (Corona) virus?

Tags: statistics, variance

Using the country/region data from this COVID-19 [dataset](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git), how can i get the population and density for a particular country/region?

I am interested in looking for variance of per capita statistics for different areas.

Comment: Using what language/tools? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: i can get and plot the data from the git repo with no problem, but i have no idea how to programmatically get human population size and density for a particular region?

Comment: Please give a [mre], then, tagging the question with what you're actually using.

Comment: You'll need a separate data source for pop/densities such as found here: https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-density/ (in csv or json).

Comment: thanks any.  make an answer so i can check it.

Comment: You can't get the number of infected, there is presently no test to prove the presence of a virus (and more, that it is the cause of illness). What you get are numbers for people tested positive for marker molecules that may or may not be related to some or even some specific virus, or may just be indicative for inflammation.

Comment: using the reported cases if fine with me. i just wanted to know local population and density figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a separate data source for pop/densities such as found here:

```
worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-density (in csv or json).
```

Good luck.